# Android ZBar SDK Get Scanned Image

Tags: android, qr-code, capture, zbar-sdk, zbar

I am using ZBar SDK for Android.

It is decoding and returning me QRCode.

But it is not returning captured image.

I want to show captured QR Image from Camera to my screen.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: maybe you will need to fetch it from camerapreview ...

Comment: check this question, there is another problem but I think the capture part you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969487/scaning-barcode-qr-code-capture-image-using-android-takepicture

Comment: @bjoshi can you have any small example code or something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're camera class is implementing Camera.PreviewCallback, you can override the onPreviewFrame method

```
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

        Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
        barcode.setData(data);
        int result = scanner.scanImage(barcode);

        if (result != 0) {
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.stopPreview();

            SymbolSet syms = scanner.getResults();
            for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                    // the barcode string
                System.out.println(sym.getData());
            }

    }
```

and then call the method by:

```
yourCamera.setPreviewCallback(YourCameraActivity.this);
```